# How to combine two rows with comma separator in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I tried as shown below

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
       (
           SELECT td.Text + ', ' AS 'data()',
                  Tda.FirmID
           FROM   tblData1 tda
                  INNER JOIN tblData2 Td
                       ON  Tda.ID = Td.ID
           GROUP BY
                  Tda.Enable1,
                  Tda.ID,
                  Td.Text
           HAVING ISNULL(Enable1, 0) = 1
                  FOR XML PATH('')
       ),
       1,
       10000
   ) AS Csv
```

**Output**:

```
Landlord Tenant, <FirmID>1</FirmID>NJ Traffic, <FirmID>1</FirmID>
```

**Expected Output**: Should be in table format

```
       csv                          FirmID
Landlord Tenant, NJ Traffic           1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the results by using **COALESCE**

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @ID NUMERIC(18,0)

SELECT  @Text = COALESCE(@Text + ', ', '') + 
        CAST(td.Text AS VARCHAR(MAX)),@ID = MAX(tda.FirmID)
FROM    tblData1 tda 
        INNER JOIN tblData2  Td 
        ON Tda.ID=Td.ID 
GROUP BY 
        Tda.Enable,
        Tda.FirmID,Td.Text
HAVING ISNULL(Enable,0)=1

SELECT @Text AS Text,@ID AS ID
```

**OutPut**:

```
      text                          ID
Landlord Tenant, NJ Traffic         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the aliases in the subquery and try this:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + td.Text
              FROM tblData2 Td 
              WHERE ISNULL(Enable1, 0) = 1
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, '') AS Csv,
       MAX(Tda.FirmID)
FROM tblData1 tda;
```

You cannot select multiple columns in the subquery either.  After all, the purpose is to combine values into a *single* column.  Multiple values in the `select` create one column, but with multiple XML tags within the string.

You also do not need the `group by` in the subquery.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'tblData1 .ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.